# Google Classroom push notification request causes Code 400: Failed Precondition

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to get my Google Classroom API to register to send push notifications to Cloud Pub/Sub.
I have successfully formed a request, and gotten through authentication. However, I've run into a code 400: Failed Precondition upon trying to execute.

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "@NoPublishPermission Classroom is unable to publish to the specified Cloud Pub/Sub topic.",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "@NoPublishPermission Classroom is unable to publish to the specified Cloud Pub/Sub topic.",
  "status" : "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

I found this description of the error:

[image]

This firstly states that I may not have billing enabled. I did not have it enabled, and I have solved this. However, the problem persists, so it may be the second problem I don't understand. The description of the issue tells me that it was an option to have some sort of encryption system set up on the topic. I don't understand what's happening. Can someone please explain?

EDIT:
I can definitely say this doesn't seem to have anything to do with "customer managed keys". My topic clearly states it is Google-managed
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the the classroom service account does not have the publish right.

In Google Cloud IAM & Admin Section > IAM

Add the service account `classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com` with role `Pub/Sub publisher` to give the publish permission.

[image: Classroom Service Account]

Comment: Thank you. This got the 400 out of the way. However, I'm getting a 404 now.

{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}

I'll just ask a new question

Comment: Looks like the [registration](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/registrations/create.html) flow needs to be looked again. Can you elaborate on when do you get this?